# Using edebug for elisp fails on can't find library

Tags: emacs, elisp

Trying to use edebug to work on an emacs lisp library. I can effectively set breakpoints and break on them when I run the defun, unfortunately when I use i to step into something, I get the error:

```
Can't find library /usr/share/emacs/23.3/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-macs.el
```

It's not lying, that library doesn't exist, only the compiled version (.elc) exists. It was installed using:

```
apt-get install emacs23-nox
```

Any ideas on how to get it going?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a Debian-derived distro, the bare `emacs23` package does not include the Elisp sources (nor any documentation, etc). To install them, `sudo apt-get install emacs23-el`